# BASH parsing and generating MYSQL insert

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have the following text line :

```
"Field1":"Data1","Field2":"Data2","Field3":"Data3","Field4":"Data4" ...
```

And I need to generate the following INSERT statement :

```
INSERT INTO data (Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4 ... ) VALUES(Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4 ... );
```

Any ideas on how to do it in BASH ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The proper Right Answer is not to use bash for this at all. See item 7 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashWeaknesses; the Right Thing is to use a language with database bindings that natively support bound parameters. Anything else opens you up to http://xkcd.com/327/ bugs (by making your code's correctness dependent on the individual database's character set conversion, quoting, and similar logic).

Comment: If you want automatic type recognition from MySQL when you use a constructed `INSERT` statement, you have to convert inputs into type forms that MySQL understands ( see 8 in the list by @CharlesDuffy ).  For a "generic" csv->Postgres script, I ended up with flags to denote column types as boolean, dates, strings, and numerics.  For example, you might want to treat "0" as a boolean sometimes ( outputting `false` ) or leave it as an integer based on the table column's type.  That's not something a script can "magically" know based on the raw inputs.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
"Field1":"Data1","Field2":"Data2","Field3":"Data3","Field4":"Data4"
$
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="^\"|\"[:,]\"|\"$" }
{
    fields = values = ""
    for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) {
        fields = fields (i>2 ? "," : "") $i
        values = values (i>2 ? "," : "") $(i+1)
    }
    printf "INSERT INTO data (%s) VALUES(%s);\n", fields, values
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
INSERT INTO data (Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4) VALUES(Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this awk command:

```
$ cat file
"Field1":"Data1","Field2":"Data2","Field3":"Data3","Field4":"Data4"
$ awk -F'[:"]+' '{s=(NR>1?",":""); fields=fields s $2;data=data s $3}END{printf "INSTERT INTO data(%s) VALUES(%s)\n", fields,data}' RS="," file
INSTERT INTO data(Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4) VALUES(Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4)
```

Or a bit more readable

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS ="[:\"]+";
    RS=",";
}
{
    s=(NR>1?",":"")
    fields=fields s $2
    data=data s $3
}
END{
    printf "INSTERT INTO data(%s) VALUES(%s)\n", fields,data
}
```

Save it in a file named `script.awk`, and run it like:

```
./script.awk file
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically asked for a BASH solution (rather than awk, perl, or python):

```
data='"Field1":"Data1","Field2":"Data2","Field3":"Data3","Field4":"Data4"'

data=${data//,/$'\n'}     # replace comma with new-lines
data=${data//\"/}         # remove the quotes
while IFS=':' read -r field item
do
    if [[ -n $fields ]]
    then
        fields="$fields,$field"
        items="$items,$item"
    else
        fields=$field
        items=$item
    fi
done < <(echo "$data")

stmt="INSERT INTO data ($fields) VALUES($items);"
echo "$stmt"
```

Comment: will fail if input contains backslashes due to missing `-r` arg for read, will produce different outputs on different systems depending on which version of echo is installed, and will have other unexpected results due to non-quoted shell variables. Don't use shell for parsing text files - it's what awk was invented to do and does best.

Comment: @EdMorton ...actually, the places where quoting is missing here is all right-hand-side of assignments or inside `[[ ]]` (which has special parse-stage behavior). Those aren't string-split or glob expanded, so quoting isn't needed in them anyhow. Also, the shell-builtin version of `echo` shadows the system binary, so echo's behavior in bash is consistent.

You're right that `read` should have `-r`, but the other criticisms are mistaken.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've never heard that `echo` is guranteed to be consistent when used in bash scripts before. OK, thanks for the info. Does bash's echo reproduce the text as-is in the output, for example does it print `\n` when it sees `\n` in the input or does it convert it to a newline character?

Comment: @EdMorton If you want something guaranteed to be consistent and safe, `printf %s "$var"` is the best practice. However, `echo "$foo"` can be considered guaranteed to emit the contents of the variable foo byte-for-byte so long as those contents are not precisely `-n`, `-e` or `-E`.

Comment: `printf` is a built-in in bash, as is echo.  It is also a built-in in ksh93 but not ksh88 where the program `printf` is used.  I accept the use of `-r` on `read`.  Modifying code.

Comment: @EdMorton: I would argue that many of the bash features I used here post-date `awk`, and even `nawk`.  Why not go the whole hog and use Perl?  Then you could call MySQL direct through the DBI.  The question specifically asked how to do this in BASH, not in xyz language.

Comment: When people ask how to do something in bash, they invariably are NOT asking for how to do it using only bash built-ins. One reason not to do it in perl is that perl does not come with all UNIX installations, unlike awk. Awk was invented to do this type of job, has the language constructs to support it, and so the resulting script is robust and concise.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/$/) VALUES(/
: next
   s/"\([^"]*\)":"\([^"]*\)"\(.*\)) VALUES(\(.*\)/\1\3) VALUES(\4,\2/
   t next
   s/VALUES(,/VALUES(/
   s/.*/INSERT INTO data (&)/
   p
   ' YourFile
```

Assuming there is no `"` in data value nor `) VALUES(` (could be treated also if needed)